# Searching for files for which we know part of the word, but too many files for wildcard in the Korn Shell

Tags: shell, search, scripting, wildcard, ksh

I am trying to locate files for which I know part of the name, lets say part of the file name is "abc" but the file could be abc123 or 123abc etc...

However, there are too many files for me to use a wildcard search (I get the too many files error I have seen others talking about, apparently if there are too many files you cannot use wildcards).

I have heard it is possible to use a For loop to achieve this, but I do not seem to be having much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*abc*' -print
```

so the shell does not have to expand wildcards. To iterate over the results:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    do something with "$filename"
done; < <(find . -name '*abc*' -print)
```

or

```
find . -name '*abc*' -print | xargs some_command_that_takes_filenames_as_arguments
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn, that was a great help! :)